# Active Directory Federation

Tags: 2010, security-token-service

I have a need to get SharePoint to communicate with an Active Directory service on a different domain, but trust is an issue.

Basically we have arp.local.org (arp.org exposed externally) that hosts two different AD controllers. This is accessible to all users from within the company domain, all good.

SharePoint 2010 will be installed and hosted externally from the company, but SP should federate access to arp.org, however, trust on the domains will be an issue. From what I know, there is no way to connect to LDAP services remotely, but SP 2010 has Geneva-features, which means that in theory, I would be able to get SP 2010 talking with ADFS on arp.org, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you would setup an ADFSv2 server, then use SharePoint in Claims mode. When a client logs in, they will access the ADFS server, then redirect into SharePoint. This is the same way Office 365 uses for authentication.

Comment: hi daniel. thanks, figured that claims would be the way to go.